# Percentage difference between values in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary as below

```
dictSumEachDay = {'2019.09.17': (558, 558),
                  '2019.09.09': (541, 552),
                  '2019.09.07': (415, 415),
                  '2019.09.11': (817, 817),
                  '2019.09.10': (755, 751),
                  '2019.09.12': (803, 771),
                  '2019.09.14': (679, 712),
                  '2019.09.06': (660, 654),
                  '2019.09.13': (737, 733),
                  '2019.09.15': (837, 837),
                  '2019.09.16': (715, 715),
                  '2019.09.08': (489, 492)}
```

And I'd like to compute the percentage difference between the values and return a dictionary such as

```
 dictPercentDiff = {'2019.09.17': 0.0,
                  '2019.09.09': 2.012808783165599,
                  '2019.09.07': 0.0,
                  '2019.09.11': 0.0,
                  '2019.09.10': 0.5312084993359893,
                  '2019.09.12': 4.066073697585769,
                  '2019.09.14': 4.744787922358016,
                  '2019.09.06': 0.91324200913242,
                  '2019.09.13': 0.5442176870748299,
                  '2019.09.15': 0.0,
                  '2019.09.16': 0.0,
                  '2019.09.08': 0.6116207951070336}
```

Already tried

```
dictPercentDiff = {}

for key, value in dictSumEachDay.items():
    top = abs(value[0] - value[1])
    bottom = (value[0] + value[1])/2
    dictPercentDiff[dictSumEachDay[key]] = (top/bottom)*100
```

Which returns:

```
{(558, 558): 0.0,
 (541, 552): 2.012808783165599,
 (415, 415): 0.0,
 (817, 817): 0.0,
 (755, 751): 0.5312084993359893,
 (803, 771): 4.066073697585769,
 (679, 712): 4.744787922358016,
 (660, 654): 0.91324200913242,
 (737, 733): 0.5442176870748299,
 (837, 837): 0.0,
 (715, 715): 0.0,
 (489, 492): 0.6116207951070336}
```

Obviously I'm mixing up keys and values but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Use this: `dictPercentDiff[key] = (top/bottom)*100`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want the % difference keyed by the day, all you need to do is to correct your final dict assignment:

```
dictPercentDiff[key] = (top/bottom)*100
```

Your posted code very specifically uses the tuple of values as the new dict's key.

Comment: This is tagged 2.7 so you need to convert to `float` if `top` and `bottom` are `int`s

Answer (score 1):

```
{key:(value[1]-value[0])/value[0] * 100 for key,value in dictSumEachDay.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with `dictPercentDiff[dictSumEachDay[key]]`. You're telling it that you want to take the key (date), find the value associated with that in `dictSumEachDay` (the tuple), and then use that as the key. If you just change it to `dictPercentDiff[key]`, that will get what you want. Also, using "numerator" and "denominator" rather than "top" and "bottom" is more clear. However, it's better to use a comprehension:

```
dictPercentDiff = {key: 200*abs(value[1]-value[0])/(value[0]+value[1]) for key, value in dictSumEachDay.items()}
```

As a further note, people generally use "percentage difference" to mean the signed difference as a percentage of the first value, while you are using it to mean the absolute value of the difference as a percentage of the average. That is, you are using `100*abs(value[1]-value[0])/((value[0]+value[1])/2)` rather than `100*(value[1]-value[0])/(value[0])`.

Answer (score 0):

below code is giving correct answer.

```
A ={'2019.09.17': (558, 558),
'2019.09.09': (541, 552),
'2019.09.07': (415, 415),
'2019.09.11': (817, 817),
'2019.09.10': (755, 751),
'2019.09.12': (803, 771),
'2019.09.14': (679, 712),
'2019.09.06': (660, 654),
'2019.09.13': (737, 733),
'2019.09.15': (837, 837),
'2019.09.16': (715, 715),
'2019.09.08': (489, 492)}

for i in A:
    if A[i][0]>A[i][-1]:
        print(abs(A[i][0]-A[i][-1])/A[i][-1]*100)
    else:
        print(abs(A[i][0]-A[i][-1])/A[i][0]*100)

Output :=>
0.0
2.033271719038817
0.0
0.0
0.5326231691078562
4.150453955901426
4.860088365243005
0.9174311926605505
0.5457025920873124
0.0
0.0
0.6134969325153374
```

Comment: The answer would be more useful if you can add some explanation along with the code.